# Can't add constraints between UICollectionView cell and the cell subview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

After I run my app, it crashes:

> Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

My image is subview of the cell.

What am I doing wrong?

```
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
image.image = UIImage.init(named: "Bitmap")

cell.contentView.addSubview(image)

let bottomConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
//let leftConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
//let rightConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let heightConstr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil , attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

image.addConstraint(bottomConstr)
//image.addConstraint(leftConstr)
//image.addConstraint(rightConstr)
image.addConstraint(heightConstr)
```

Comment: you need to add constraint on  contentView like cell.contentView.addConstraint(bottomConstr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add constraint on Superview. so, add it on cell `contentView`.

```
  cell.contentView.addConstraint(bottomConstr)
  cell.contentView.addConstraint(heightConstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraints weren't working well for me when zooming UICollectionView. Here's how I resized a label to always fill the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mycell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SliceCollectionViewCell
    cell.label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                             forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? MyCollectionViewCell else {
        print("ERROR: wrong cell type")
        return
    }
    cell.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
}
```